# Prove that $3x=4y$ given the circle.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, circles

I was trying to prove that $3x=4y$ using the intersecting secants theorem. I am stuck to what to do after my solution.

$3x(3x+3)=3y(3y+11)\rightarrow9x^2+9x=9y^2+33y $

$2x(2x+4)=2y(2y+10)\rightarrow4x^2+8x=4y^2+20y$

I then subtracted the two equations and I got $5x^2+x=5y^2+13y$.

I am stuck here and don't know what to do. We were supposed to use circle theorems for segments because that is our lesson. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: similar triangles do the trick

Comment: Or the properties of [the power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point). But for heaven's sake read [the abridged guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619) and fix your post.

Comment: I edited the question and included my attempt.

Comment: Good. Voting to reopen. What happens if you multiply the latter equation by 9/4 before you subtract it from the former?

Comment: If my calculation is correct, i would get $9x^2+18x=9y^2+45y$, then i would get $9x=12y$, then simplify it to $3x=4y$

Comment: Good. Now that the question is reopened you can post that as an answer. When you plug the relation into either one of the others, you can also solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Don't simply subtract, try to cancel the quadratic terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3y(3y+11) = 3x(3x+3)$$
$$3y^2+11y = 3x^2+3x$$
$$3(y^2-x^2) = 3x-11y\tag{1}\label{1}$$

$$2y(2y+10) = 2x(2x+4)$$
$$y^2+5y = x^2+2x$$
$$y^2-x^2 = 2x-5y\tag{2}\label{2}$$

From $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$:
$$3(2x-5y) = 3x-11y$$
$$6x-15y = 3x-11y$$
$$3x = 4y$$

Now:
$$3y(3y+11) = 4y(4y+3)$$
$$9y+33 = 16y+12$$
$$\color{green}{y = 3}$$
$$\color{green}{x = 4}$$